# NGINX: Route a call to localhost on a custom port to an external server

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with my rails app.

An API of the app is looking for my forum (forum.example.com) on localhost on port 8082.

I need to create a route that redirect every connection to 127.0.0.1:8082 at forum.example.com

Is possible to obtain something like this with nginx?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for this.

In nginx, create a virtual host that listen on port `8082` for `localhost` and then proxy this to `forum.example.com`.

Something like this :

```
server {
   listen 8082;
   server_name 127.0.0.1;
   location / {
      proxy_pass http://forum.example.com;
   }
}
```